# sq server, query considering values from "as" columns

Tags: php, sql-server

i got this php and I need to get some KPI's from the values comming from the first part of the query but they give only the names given before and no the values. What I need to change from the las part of the select to get the values and not the names?

```
SELECT hist_eqmtlist.unit,
       hist_statusevents.eqmt, 
       hist_exproot.shiftdate, 
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =1 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as 'Efectivo',
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =2 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as 'Demora',
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =3 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as 'Reserva',
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =4 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as 'Mantencion',
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =5 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as 'Averia',
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =6 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as 'Accidente'
       (Efectivo+Demora+Reserva)/(Efectivo+Demora+Reserva+Mantencion+Averia+Accidente) as 'Disp. Fisica'
FROM hist_eqmtlist,hist_exproot,hist_statusevents
WHERE hist_exproot.shiftindex = hist_statusevents.shiftindex And hist_statusevents.shiftindex = hist_eqmtlist.shiftindex And hist_statusevents.eqmt = hist_eqmtlist.eqmtid And hist_eqmtlist.unit='Dozer          ' AND hist_exproot.shiftdate='2011-01-02'
GROUP BY hist_statusevents.eqmt, hist_exproot.shiftdate, hist_eqmtlist.unit
order by hist_exproot.shiftdate,hist_statusevents.eqmt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column names Efectivo , Reserva , Mantencion... are not accessible in the calling query, but you can use these column names in an outer query something like this....

Also use square Brackets `[]` for object names.

```
SELECT *
,(Efectivo+Demora+Reserva)/(Efectivo+Demora+Reserva+Mantencion+Averia+Accidente) as [Disp. Fisica]
FROM (
SELECT hist_eqmtlist.unit,
       hist_statusevents.eqmt, 
       hist_exproot.shiftdate, 
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =1 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Efectivo],
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =2 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Demora],
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =3 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Reserva],
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =4 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Mantencion],
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =5 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Averia],
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =6 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Accidente]
FROM tableNames ) A
```

**Your Query**

```
SELECT *
,(Efectivo+Demora+Reserva)/(Efectivo+Demora+Reserva+Mantencion+Averia+Accidente) as [Disp. Fisica]
FROM (
SELECT hist_eqmtlist.unit,
       hist_statusevents.eqmt, 
       hist_exproot.shiftdate, 
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =1 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Efectivo],
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =2 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Demora],
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =3 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Reserva],
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =4 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Mantencion],
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =5 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Averia],
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =6 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Accidente]
FROM hist_eqmtlist 
INNER JOIN  hist_statusevents   ON  hist_statusevents.shiftindex = hist_eqmtlist.shiftindex 
                               AND  hist_statusevents.eqmt = hist_eqmtlist.eqmtid 
INNER JOIN  hist_exproot        ON  hist_exproot.shiftindex = hist_statusevents.shiftindex
WHERE  hist_eqmtlist.unit     = 'Dozer' 
   AND hist_exproot.shiftdate = '2011-01-02'
GROUP BY hist_statusevents.eqmt, hist_exproot.shiftdate, hist_eqmtlist.unit
) A
order by A.shiftdate,A.eqmt
```

Comment: `It didnt work` is a very vague term, what didn't work exactly ? you got an error message? it didn't show the results as you were expecting ? or something else ????

Comment: I misunderstood your explanation

Comment: thanks a lot!! I will study the structure to learn more about the inner join also

Comment: I realize Than te division could result as error because de division by 0, when all the factors are 0....